# Deleting a column and shifting left in Excel if a value in a cell on that column is below a threshold using macros?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set for an unrelated classification problem I am going true, and I want to cut down on the number of attribute totals. I've put my data set into a CSV format which excel handles quite nicely, but I need to make some changes - and I've never done any VBA so the syntax seems extremely foreign to me.

Basically, I have 7071 columns (attributes) and 70 rows (instances). Cells below each of the columns (say A75 for column A) contain a certain statistic method for attribute evaluation. **What I want to do** is check against the value in this cell ("A75" in this example), and if it is below a certain threshold, delete the entire column as well as shift everything to the left. So if I had something like :

`o   A  B   C  D ... XYZ`

`1   2  5   4  9 ...  2`

`2   3  9   0  1 ...  3`

`3   1  1   5  6 ...  0`

`...`

`75 0.23 0.5 0.6 0.44 ... 0.8`

And my calculations determined that the minimum threshold is 0.3, then the macro would get rid of column A and shift the others to the left:

`o   A   B  C ... XYZ`

`1   5   4  9 ...  2`

`2   9   0  1 ...  3`

`3   1   5  6 ...  0`

`...`

`75 0.5 0.6 0.44 ... 0.8`

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you.  If you deleting rows or columns begin deleting from the end and move to the start (ie right to left or bottom to top).

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveColumns()
    Dim vEvalRange As Variant, ii As Integer

    'NOTE: This assumes the usedrange starts at cell A1!

    'Screen updating when deleting cells slows things down
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Set your evaluation row to an array.  It's faster to sort through variables than sheet ranges
    vEvalRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Value

    'count from right to left otherwise your columns will shift and mess up your array
    For ii = UBound(vEvalRange, 2) To LBound(vEvalRange, 2) Step -1
        If vEvalRange(1, ii) < 0.3 Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(ii).Delete
        End If
    Next ii

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I made some adjustments of course, but that was quite like what I needed.